# Linear span of functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Maybe this is something basic but I am not familiar with the term "linear span" and in one question it mentions

> the linear span of the functions $f_n(t) = e^{nt}$, $n = 0,1,2,...$ $t \in [a,b]$

What I understood is linear span is the set of linear combination of all elements but I am still unable to understand what that set is.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The linear span of a set $V$ consists of all vectors $w$ of the form
$$w=c_1 v_1+c_2v_2+\cdots+c_n v_n$$ where the $c_i$ are scalars, the $v_i$ are vectors in $V$ and $n$ is a positive integer.

So, in your case the linear span of the functions $\{f_n\}$ is the set of all finite linear combinations of the $f_n$. An element of the linear span has the form:
$$
\tag{1}f(t)=c_1 e^{n_1t}+c_2 e^{n_2t}+\cdots+ c_m e^{n_m t},
$$
where $m$ is a positive integer, the $n_i$ are non-negative integers, and the $c_i$ are scalars.

In particular, 
$$
f(t)=e^t-2e^{4t}+237 e^{32t}
$$
is in the linear span,
as is
$$
f(t)=3+e^t
$$
$(e^{0t}=1$).

The linear span is the set of all functions of the form in (1).

Comment: +1 for clarity. But there's a typo: your $c_ne^{c_nt}$ should be something like $c_ke^{n_kt}$.

Comment: @Clive Newstead Arg, thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Well, as you said, $f\in \operatorname{span} \{ e^{n t},\ n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ iff there exist $N\in \mathbb{N}$ and $N$ real numbers $\alpha_0, \ldots , \alpha_N$ such that:
$$f(t)=\sum_{n=0}^N \alpha_n\ e^{nt}$$
(this by the very definition of *linear combination*), therefore:
$$\operatorname{span} \{ e^{n t},\ n\in \mathbb{N}\} =\Bigg\{ \sum_{n=0}^N \alpha_n\ e^{nt},\ N\in \mathbb{N},\ \alpha_0, \ldots , \alpha_N \in \mathbb{R}\Bigg\} \; .$$

Comment: I think there is a problem with $\sum_{n=0}^N \alpha_n\ e^{nt}$. It looks like $n$ in $e^{nt}$ cannot be greater than $N$. But it can, right?

Comment: @marvinthemartian note, some of the $\alpha_n$ can be 0. $N$, of course, is arbitrary.

Comment: @DavidMitra Ooooo.. okey. I got it now :)